# How can I write "ó" in Android Studio on layout?

Tags: android, layout, character

I am intented to write `Iniciar sesión`, but the `ó` not working. For this reason I changed to `&oacute;` but is another error.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:text="Inicio de sesi&oacute;n"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />
```

¿I must configure Android Studio?

I added `compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1"` in `build.gradle` but the error persist.

Help me, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you have to create a `Strings.xml` file and add to it and qualifier (Spanish language) then you can add this letter with accent without any problem

```
<resources> <!-- spanish language qualifier -->
    <string name="test_text">Iniciar sesión </string>
</resources>
```

You can read more about qualifiers in the oficial documentation here:

[Qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to use text like this, directly on your layout file. Instead of it, you should relay on the file **string.xml** where you define all the texts your xml files will need to display. By doing this, you will be doing nothing less than the correct specification from Android makers in order to localize your app (more info on this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html ).

So, proceed this way:

1) on your **res** folder there is another one called **values**. There you will find your **strings.xml** file. Open it and create a new key, let's call it **txtarriba**, like this:

```
<string name="txtarriba">Begin of session</string>
```

2) with android studio or your regular file manager, create another folder below your **res** folder, call it **values-ES**.

3) inside **values-ES** create a new file named **strings.xml**, there you will insert the translation of that key **txtarriba**. So do this:

```
<string name="txtarriba">Inicio de sesión</string>
```

4) Then, on your primitive layout xml file you define your textview like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="330dp"
android:layout_height="24dp"
android:text="@string/txtarriba"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />
```

DONE.

With this you can assure you app is, from now on, correctly showed according to your device idiom. If your device is in english, **Begin of session** will be showed. If device is set with spanish language, you will read **Inicio de sesión**. With this you can forget all the troubles about special chars, Android manages this for you ;)